# JS - How to return mysql query values properly

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm pretty new to JS since I've switched from C#.

My Question is how I can return mysql query values without problems.

```
chat.registerCmd('getid', (player, arg) => {
    
    

    
    
    db.getPlayerPermission(player.socialId, function(permission){
        PermissionValue = permission;
    });
       

    var vname;
    var name;

    if(arg.length <= 1) {
        chat.send(player, '/getid [Vorname] [Name]');
        return;
    }
    vname = arg[0];
    name = arg[1];

    db.getCharIdByName(vname, name, function(charid){
        chat.send(player, 'Die ID des Spielers ist: ' + charid);
    });
 });
```

Is this a good way to return query values?

```
export function getPlayerPermission(socialid, callback){
connection.query('SELECT permission FROM permissions WHERE socialid=?',socialid, function(err, rows){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    callback(rows[0].permission);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a callback-based approach which is completely fine. You can also use promises. With the callback apparoach, you can return both errors and the result of queries. The first argument can be the error while the second argument can be the returned value

```js
export function getPlayerPermission(socialid, callback) {
  connection.query('SELECT permission FROM permissions WHERE socialid=?',socialid, 
    function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        callback(null, rows[0].permission);
    });
}
```

Now in your other file, you can call the function as follows

```js
chat.registerCmd('getid', (player, arg) => { 
    db.getPlayerPermission(player.socialId, function(dbErr, permission) {
        // since JS is asynchronous, you need to be in callback function to execute the rest of the code after you get the data from first query
        if (dbErr) {
           console.log(dbErr);
           return;
        }
        // Now permission variable has data returned from the query
        PermissionValue = permission;
        var vname;
        var name;

        if(arg.length <= 1) {
           chat.send(player, '/getid [Vorname] [Name]');
           return;
        }
        vname = arg[0];
        name = arg[1];

        db.getCharIdByName(vname, name, function(charid){
            chat.send(player, 'Die ID des Spielers ist: ' + charid);
        });
     });
 });
```